# Activating PHP extension from php file

Tags: php

I have apache/PHP - WINDOWS server.
I have 2 different sites (www.example.com and test.example.com) I have used vhosts to configure my subdomain.

Is it possible to load different php.ini files for each subdomain ?
I have a problem with the first site which is coming from using extension for the second site. 
So I need to enable it for the second ONLY or to disable it for the first only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't activate php extension from php file. You can only check loading of a specific ext.

Comment: Can I set my appache to load different php.ini then for the different subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

Extensions can be enabled programmatically on *some* SAPIs with

- [dl — Loads a PHP extension at runtime](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)

Please read the manual carefully for security implications and forward compatibility issues.

For more options, see

- http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

Many settings in the php.ini can be overridden in the .htaccess file, or in the executing script itself.  Look at the list: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php and refer to the Changeable column for details.

If by "extension" you mean a php extension, then no, you can't have a different php extension on the same server, because php is shared.  The only way you would be able to accomplish that would be to have a 2nd apache server running.  If this is truly a test site, a separate server would be feasible because you could run it on a separate port, but I wouldn't suggest going that route unless you were highly confident in your skills as a windows sysadmin.